# REACT, have a variable that rolls a num 1-10 and concatenating that variable in return statement in JSX. Number is rolled 2x before rendered on screen

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jsx

In the process of learning react and just building a simple number guessing game for practice purposes

In my code, I have a component named 'Game' with 'const roll = Math.floor(Math.random() * 10 + 1)' to roll a random number between 1-10 and verifying the roll by console.log so I can see the number displayed on the console.

I then use {roll} in my return statement which is later instantiated on my App.js file (App.js is not shown below)

The only thing is that the random number rolled when using console.log(roll) is different vs the number being rendered on screen in my return statement 'The number rolled is {roll}'

Why is this? I never had this issue in vanilla JavaScript but it seems like the roll is happening twice instead of taking the initial value in 'const roll'

Can anyone explain why this is the case and how to fix this problem? Thanks for any help I can get

```
import React, {useState} from "react";

const Game = () => {
    const roll = Math.floor(Math.random() * 10 + 1);
    console.log(roll);

    const guess = () => {
        let inputGuess = document.querySelector('.input');
        console.log(inputGuess.value);
    }

    const [lives, setLives] = useState(5);

    return (
        <React.Fragment>
            <h1 className='header'>Guess the number!</h1>
            <p className='roll'>The number rolled is <strong>{roll}</strong></p>
            <p className='lives'><strong>{lives}</strong> lives remaining</p>
            <p className='message'>Enter a number between 1-10</p>
            <input type='text' className='input'></input>
            <button className='guess' onClick={guess}>Guess</button>
        </React.Fragment>
    )
}

export default Game;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In dev mode, React intentionally [invokes function component bodies (and other lifecycle methods) twice](https://reactjs.org/docs/strict-mode.html#detecting-unexpected-side-effects) to help identify side-effects:

> Strict mode can’t automatically detect side effects for you, but it can help you spot them by making them a little more deterministic. This is done by intentionally double-invoking the following functions:

- Class component constructor, render, and shouldComponentUpdate methods
- Class component static getDerivedStateFromProps method
- Function component bodies
- State updater functions (the first argument to setState)
- Functions passed to useState, useMemo, or useReducer

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Removing strict mode from index.js 'fixed' the problem. Should i just build project with the strict mode disabled or if it is ideal to wrap strict mode around App.js, how do i get around this issue when trying to trigger roll only one time?

Comment: You should not remove strict mode. The way you have it written you're going to get a new roll every time your Game component re-renders. If that's a problem you should do the roll differently, not disable the very thing that brought the problem to your attention. There are many ways to approach it, with useState being the most obvious. Side note: You also shouldn't be querying the DOM to get the input value in your button click handler.

Answer (score 1):

*to add to the answer by ray hatfield*

You should consider, that your `roll` variable will be re-declared (and therefore be a new random number) on every render. The component will re-render whenever the `lives` state is updated, and whenever the parent-component re-renders.

To prevent the re-assignment of the roll variable you should place it in its own `useState` hook.

Try:

```js
const Game = () => {
    const roll = Math.floor(Math.random() * 10 + 1);
    const [roll2, setRoll] = React.useState(Math.floor(Math.random() * 10 + 1));
    console.log('Without useState: ', roll);
    console.log('With useState: ', roll2);

    const guess = () => {
        let inputGuess = document.querySelector('.input');
        console.log(inputGuess.value);
    }

    const [lives, setLives] = React.useState(5);

    return (
        <React.Fragment>
            <h1 className='header'>Guess the number!</h1>
            <p className='roll'>The number rolled is <strong>{roll}</strong></p>
            <p className='lives'><strong>{lives}</strong> lives remaining</p>
            <p className='message'>Enter a number between 1-10</p>
            <input type='text' className='input'></input>
            <button className='guess' onClick={guess}>Guess</button>
        </React.Fragment>
    )
};

const App = () => {
    console.log('re-rendering App');
    const [state, setState] = React.useState(0);

    // we are faking an update to the parent component
    React.useEffect(() => {
        setInterval(() => setState((prev) => ++prev), [2000]);
    }, []);
    
    return <div><Game /></div>;
}
ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById('app'));
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/react@17/umd/react.development.js" crossorigin ></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@17/umd/react-dom.development.js" crossorigin ></script>
<div id="app"></div>
```